# Shell script to execute a command with iteration

Tags: shell, shell-script

This is a script which looks for `.tab` files in a folder an should imports them with
`ogr2ogr`, but I fail with the correct bracing.

```
for i in $( ls *.tab )
do
  echo item: $i

  ogr2ogr -f PostgreSQL -s_srs EPSG:21781 -t_srs EPSG:4326 -overwrite \
          -nln $TBL_NAME PG:'"host=localhost user='$DBUSER' dbname='$DBNAME'"' $i
done
```

And I need a command line to execute the `ogr2ogr` section in this way:

```
ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" -s_srs "EPSG:21781" -t_srs "EPSG:4326" -overwrite \
        -nln "geom_tour" PG:"host=localhost user=postgres dbname=gis" DMC_34093.tab
```

Comment: Was tired and overworked, edited my question and added the snipped...

Comment: You forgot the `host=localhost` part in your code. Also why don't you just do `for i in *.tab`? And what is that code assigning to variable `j` for?

Comment: Thx for the comment. j was from something else, removed it now added the host=localhost (which isn't necessary) - still not working... Problem is in the braces :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Should be:

```
for i in *.tab
do
  echo item: $i

  ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" -s_srs "EPSG:21781" -t_srs "EPSG:4326" -overwrite -nln "$TBL_NAME" PG:"host=localhost user=\'${DBUSER}\' dbname=\'${DBNAME}\'" "$i"
done
```

You need to use double quotes to let the shell expand variables like `${DBUSER}` inside.

Note `for i in *.tab` instead of <s>`for i in $(ls *.tab)`</s>. [Don't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), all it does is mangle file names with spaces and other special characters.